# Find the reverse of a number (ex : 2500 reverse 0025) without the help of string or character

Tags: c++, c

Is there any technique for finding the reverse when there are zeros at the end.

While following the algorithm of %10 technique the result is 52. And the 0's are missing.

I have got the reverse by just printing the reminders (with 0's). But I am not satisfied as I wish to display the answer as the value in a variable.

Kindly tell me is there any technique to store a value 005 to a variable and also to display 005 (please don't use String or Character or array).

Comment: Why is `2500` not `0052` in reverse.  Btw since 2500 == 002500 could it be 005200.

Comment: you can print the leading zeroes but you can't store them. alternatively you can use arrays.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun Nice bending of the rules ;)

Comment: Do you have to store the reversed number or is it OK to only store the original number and reverse it when printing?

Comment: @Njol yes i need to store. but that's not a matter i could use a 3rd variable to store that value. so its ok

Comment: I think you should use a simple struct with a constructor to store all this information. The key 'take-away' from this SO question is that 0052 is _not_ an integer, it is a string. The easiest way to get what you want is to implement very simple, small, specialized string class to do what you want.

Comment: A number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number is a number. :( If you want a string of digits, that's not what a number is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numbers are stored as binary 0 and 1 and so they always have leading 0's which are chopped off. e.g. a 64-bit integer has 64-bit bits, *always* and when it is printed these leading 0's are dropped.

You need to know how many leading zeros you want to keep and only use that many when you  print.  i.e. you can record how many leading zeros there were in a normal number without encoding it e.g. by adding a 1 at the start. i.e. `0052` is recorded as `10052` and you skip the first digit when you print.

If you need to store a single value you can do the following. I use do/while so that `0` becomes `10` and is printed as `0`. The number `0` is the one place where not all leading zeros are dropped (as it would be empty otherwise)

---

**This appears to be the solution you want and it should be basically the same in C or C++**

```
static long reverse(long num) {
    long rev = 1; // the 1 marks the start of the number.
    do {
        rev = rev * 10 + num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    } while(num != 0);
    return rev;
}

// make the reversed number printable.
static String toStringReversed(long num) {
    return Long.toString(num).substring(1);
}

long l = reverse(2500); // l = 10052
```

---

An alternative is to print the digits as you go and thus not need to store it.

e.g.

```
static void printReverse(long l) {
    do {
        System.out.print(l % 10);
        l /= 10;
    } while(l != 0);
}
```

or you can have the input record the number of digits.

```
static void printReverse(long l, int digits) {
    for(int i = 0; i < digits; i++) {
        System.out.print(l % 10);
        l /= 10;
    }
}

// prints leading zero backwards as well
printReverse(2500, 6); // original number is 002500
```

prints

```
005200
```

Comment: 0052 is recorded as 10052 part I am impressed sir. but the code you have shown is not satisfactory. as its just printing the reminder one at a time. and not as a value in a variable. :(

also please tell how 0052 is stored as 10052. then i will accept the answer

Comment: @MELWIN In Java you would do `Long.toString(num).substring(1);` to "decode" leading zeros.

Comment: @MELWIN It has a been too long since I did those.  The code should be almost exactly the same. Perhaps you can use `long long` instead.

Comment: no sir I meant can you help me of telling "how the number 0052 is stored as 10052". I am happy from your answer that to find reverse of 2500 we can make it first 25001 and then display using printReverse(2500, 6); technique. a mix of logic. hope you understood. kindly edit printReverse(2500, 6); using a variable in place of 2500. please

Comment: storing number length as a seperate variable is easier

Comment: @MELWIN I suggest you read the first piece of code again.  This is what it does already. It's not even as complicated as adding a `1` to the end.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc can you explain how. please

Comment: @PeterLawrey :) thank you. if you could edit i could vote up. Thank you... Satisfied :)

Comment: for example 5200 -> length = 4. When reversing it becomes 25, then just padding the remaining zeros

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc simpler than that is to just keep printing digits until you have 4. See the for loop example above.

Comment: @PeterLawrey that'll work when the length is always 4. I don't know the OP's problem has fixed width or not

Comment: What if my own custom virtual machine stores *numbers* as strings of decimal digits instead of strings of binary digits (aka bits), as this answer seems to assume? How would this explanation relate to that system? IOW, is this really a shortcoming of representing numbers in base 2, or does it maybe stem from some other factor?

Comment: (Those are all rhetorical questions; food for thought, if you will. The answer to the last one is "no, the storage mechanism is irrelevant; this is a semantic issue")

Answer (score 5):

You cannot represent an integer with leading zeros as a single integer variable, that information is simply not part of the way bits are allocated in an integer. You must use something larger, i.e. a string or an array of individual (small integer) digits.

Comment: This is such a good answer. This, along with the "002500" example, made my day.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store them in a simple integer variable because in binary format

00101 is same as 000101 which is same as 101 which only results into 5. The convertion between a decimal number and binary numbers don't consider leading zeroes so it is not possible to store leading zeroes with the same integer variable.

You can print it but you can't store the leading zeroes unless you use array of ints...

```
int num = 500;

while(num > 0)
{
    System.out.print(num%10);
    num = num/10;
}
```

Alternatively you can store the count of leading zeroes as a separate entity and combine them when ever you need to use. As shown below.

```
int num = 12030;
boolean leading=true;
int leadingCounter = 0;
int rev = 0;
while(num > 0)
{
    int r = num%10;
    if(r == 0 && leading == true)
        leadingCounter++;
    else
        leading = false;
    rev = rev*10 + r;
    num = num/10;
}
for(int i = 1; i <= leadingCounter ; i++)
    System.out.print("0");
System.out.println(rev);
```

Comment: I have added another way of adding storing the number of leading zeroes after reversing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the accepted answer is a good one, in that it both refutes the parts of the question that are wrong and also offers a solution that will work. However, the code there is all Java, and it doesn't expose the prettiest API. Here's a C++ version that based on the code from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21109147/29182).

(Ha ha for all my talk, my answer didn't reverse the string! Best day ever!)

After going back to school and getting a degree, I came up with this answer: it has the makes the somewhat dubious claim of "not using strings" or converting any values to string. Can't avoid characters, of course, since we are printing the value in the end.

```
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>

class ReverseLong {
  public:

    ReverseLong(long value) {
      long num = value;
      bool leading = true;
      this->value = 0;
      this->leading_zeros = 0;

      while (num != 0) {
        int digit = num % 10;
        num = num / 10;

        if (leading && digit == 0) {
          this->leading_zeros += 1;
        } else {
          this->value = this->value * 10 + digit;
          leading = false;
        }
      }
    };

    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream& out, ReverseLong const & r);

  private:
    long value;
    int leading_zeros;

};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream& out, ReverseLong const & r) {

  for (int i =0; i < r.leading_zeros; i++) {
    out << 0;
  }

  out << r.value;

  return out;
};

int main () {
  ReverseLong f = ReverseLong(2500); // also works with numbers like "0"!

  std::cout << f << std::endl; / prints 0052
};
```